# How to remove several columns from a matrix

Tags: matrix, fortran

```
Integer :: NBE,ierr,RN,i,j
Real(kind=8), allocatable :: AA1(:,:),AA2(:,:)

NBE=40 
RN=3*NBE-2
Allocate(AA1(3*NBE,3*NBE),AA2(3*NBE,RN),stat=ierr)

If (ierr .ne. 0) Then
    print *, 'allocate steps failed 1'
    pause
End If

Do i=1,3*NBE
  Do j=1,3*NBE
     AA1(i,j)=1
  End Do
End Do
```

I want to remove columns 97 and 113 from the matrix `AA1` and then this matrix becomes `AA2`. I just want to know if any command of Fortran can realize this operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Alexander Vogt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48365227/3157076) gives the concept of using a *vector subscript* to select the elements of the array for inclusion.  That answer constructs the vector subscript array using

```
[(i,i=1,96),(i=98,112),(i=114,3*NBE)]
```

Some may consider

```
AA2 = AA1(:,[(i,i=1,96),(i=98,112),(i=114,3*NBE)])
```

to be less than clear in reading.  One could use a "temporary" index vector

```
integer selected_columns(RN)
selected_columns = [(i,i=1,96),(i=98,112),(i=114,3*NBE)]
AA2 = AA1(:,selected_columns)
```

but that doesn't address the array constructor being not nice, especially in more complicated cases.  Instead, we can create a mask and use our common techniques:

```
logical column_wanted(3*NBE)
integer, allocatable :: selected_columns(:)

! Create a mask of whether a column is wanted
column_wanted = .TRUE.
column_wanted([97,113]) = .FALSE.

! Create a list of indexes of wanted columns
selected_columns = PACK([(i,i=1,3*NBE)],column_wanted)
AA2 = AA1(:,selected_columns)
```

Comment: Good answer. However, I found an error in the PACK command. It should be PACK([(i,i=1,3*NBE)],column_wanted).

Comment: Thanks, I had mixed up which array had which size.  There was also a mistake the other way earlier in the answer.  Corrected now (I hope).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple one liner:

```
AA2 = AA1(:,[(i,i=1,96),(i=98,112),(i=114,3*NBE)])
```

Explanation:

1. (Inner part) Construct a temporary array for the indices `[1,...,96,98,...,112,114,...,3*NBE]`
2. (Outer part) Copy the matrix and only consider the columns in the index array

---

OK, I yield to @IanBush... Even simpler would be to do three dedicated assignments:

```
AA2(:,1:96)   = AA1(:,1:96)
AA2(:,97:111) = AA1(:,98:112)
AA2(:,112:)   = AA1(:,114:)
```

Comment: Simple!? I'd definitely write that as 3 lines, one for each "chunk"

Comment: @IanBush Mhm, okay... Though I prefer to keep my code as concise as possible. I updated my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fortran compiler here at home, so I cant test it. But I'd do something line this:

```
i = 0
DO j = 1, 3*NBE
    IF (j == 97 .OR. j == 113) CYCLE
    i = i + 1
    AA2(:, i) = AA1(:, j)
END DO
```

The `CYCLE` command means that the rest of the loop should not be executed any more and the next iteration should start. Thereby, `i` will not get incremented, so when `j=96`, then `i=96`, when `j=98` then `i=97`, and when `j=114` then `i=112`.

A few more words: Due to Fortran's memory layout, you want to cycle over the first index the fastest, and so forth. So your code would run faster if you changed it to:

```
Do j=1,3*NBE    ! Outer loop over second index
  Do i=1,3*NBE  ! Inner loop over first index
    AA1(i,j)=1
  End Do
End Do
```

(Of course, such an easy initialisation can be done even easier with just `AA1(:,:) = 1` of just `AA1 = 1`.